# ThingsBoard installation failed! On Ubuntu

Tags: thingsboard

I am trying to install thingsboard PE instance on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
 while I run this command

```
sudo /usr/share/thingsboard/bin/install/install.sh --loadDemo
```

I am facing the following error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
ThingsBoard installation failed!

the thingsboard.log file is not present in /var/log/thingsboard
```

Can anyone please suggest me what's the reason for this error?

Comment: I haven‘t tried this, but maby try to create the log first? ```touch /var/log/thingsboard/thingsboard.log```
does this solve the Problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the thingsboard database does actually exist.   I had the same error.   I did follow the instructions, but possibly the CREATE DATABASE was not followed by ';' or it needed to be started.

1. Restart the ubuntu server.
2. Log in and log onto PSQL:  psql -U postgres -d postgres -h 127.0.0.1 -W
3. Check for existence of the database:  \list
4. If it does not exists, run:  CREATE DATABASE thingsboard;
5. Run \list again and make sure it exists.  Quit by running \q.
6. Re-run the demo create script:  sudo /usr/share/thingsboard/bin/install/install.sh --loadDemo

Happy Thing-ing.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the above as Antony Horne has suggested, also you can remove the ThingsBoard related directories under /tmp/. Remove and recreate the 'thingsboard' database. Make sure to set the password as 'postgres'. Then re-run the command

```
/usr/share/thingsboard/bin/install/install.sh --loadDemo
```

It should be fine.

Though after that, when I tried to run the 'thingsboard' as

```
service thingsboard start
```

Its is not working as 'thingsboard' is unrecognized. Couldn't solve that yet.